# Is it recommended to notify the answer "Edits" with an heading followed by the edit content?

Tags: discussion, edits

Many times I see that when an user edits his own answer he notify it with an heading like this:

> #### Edit
>
> content added to the previous version of the answer

I don't like it very much because in my opinion this make the answer more ugly. And I think that it is more useful to integrate the content, adjusting the part without any heading. I don't know if this is not a good practice, and I imagine that someone can think that with the edit heading it is easier to see the improvements and that the previous up-vote refers to the original question, but in fact I think that this does not make much sense. What is the best practice?

Comment: Often I just use this to show what has changed. Sometimes when questions become moving targets, it's the easiest way to point at your changes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Messages like that do not belong in the post body. They belong in the edit reason, which is visible on the revision history page. That is *exactly* what that reason is there for - to identify why a change was made.

An edited post already has a link to the revision history as well as who edited it last and when. There's no need to keep track of its history in the post when a user could just look at the history and see what changed.

Remove lines like this whenever you see them.

Comment: Further, don't edit posts just by adding new information at the end.  The post should always be coherent as if it were written afresh -- *integrate* your changes into the post; don't concatenate.

Comment: Who are you that I am mindful of you? (Yes, I know what it says on your profile). I am happy for people to edit my posts for good technical reasons. I get immensely peeved when people edit my posts in order to detract from technical content while adding  flowers, perfume, misc stylistic "improvements" [tm] and general extraneous garbage. I place no great store in "rep", but when said abusers have very modest rep on SE overall after 4 + years of membership and to add insult to injury quote this post* of yours in justification it helpeth not a tad. |
* Which is why I am here.