# Facility to search for posts that need editing ('edit' or 'update' tags)

Tags: feature-request, edits, updating-questions

I have recently been trying to get rid of the posts where they label an edit with an "Edit:" marker. I think that an option should be added to the Stack Exchange network home page for questions needing editing which would include questions including "Edit:" or "Update:" markers.

Comment: Related: *[Is it recommended to notify the answer “Edits” with an heading followed by the edit content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230693)*

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate the effort you are doing to keep the site clean. Unfortunately, there are a lot of 'bad post indicators' and it I am sure every one has a lot of false positives. Therefore, and it's limited use to most users, I don't think it is very useful.

An option could be to show a *warning* message (like the 'this post can't contain XXX' messages) suggesting people to edit the 'Edit:' out.

Comment: I like this idea better.

Comment: Would you please open a new question with this.

Comment: I will. Give me some time though. Am a little busy today.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to make sure that you wanted to because otherwise I was going to reference you and post it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how this would be useful to the majority of people. If you're looking for posts to improve through editing (a laudable project), the search utility is there for you to use.

Comment: I have been trying that but it doesn't always work right.

Answer (score 1):

I've made [a Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/770297/post-containing-edit-or-update) for this. When you click the "Run query" button, you will get a list of the top 100 posts on the chosen site that contain "Edit:", "EDIT", "Update:" or "UPDATE".